# Use now ASUS XONAR DGX

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1803

Bought recently a new card but freezes in a different period of time:
Windows 10 x64, Xonar DGX, driver v1.81a r2, Windows 1803.
Conditions at the moment:

1. Realtek turned off in BIOS
2. All other sound devices turned off in Windows control panel.
3. No "Dolby access" or "Dolby Atmos" installed.
4. Sound volume is at 76.

But, anyway, after all these manipulations the Sound worked for about an hour and got frozen, all media stopped working. The sound appears only after a PC restart.

Could you advise anything on the subject for a stable system work without any headache? Cause it`s really mind-blasting. Tried earlier driver versions – the situation is even worse.

Comment: It seems to be a common problem for common users of these cards. I am just asking for the help - the sound is really different in 5.1 channel

Comment: The problem is in Windows Audio, which is stopped in some way but I can`t inderstand why. Tried the Restart tool from their web site - it works only time for my system.

Comment: Probably, there is another way to stop restating Windows Audio and other tools..?